# Different address when using print &var in gdb

Tags: c, assembly, memory, gdb, stack

I am practicing buffer overflow (on x86) and stuck on address presentation in gdb.
In the C source code i have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  volatile int modified;
  char buffer[64];

  modified = 0;
  gets(buffer);

  if(modified != 0) {
      printf("you have changed the 'modified' variable\n");
  } else {
      printf("Try again?\n");
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-zero/)

The assembly code (partially)

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
and esp, 0xfffffff0  # -> after the execution esp is 0xbffffd20
sub esp, 0x60        # -> after the execution the value is 0xbffffcc0
mov DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c], 0x0
```

I assume that based on the last instruction - the modified value will be located first on the stack - meaning it will be in address 0xbffffcc0 + 0x5c = 0xBFFFFD1C.

But in gdb - when i print the variable using 'p &modified' I am getting totally a different address which is 0xbffffd84.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is expected offset of the modified variable? if it is in the offset 0xBFFFFD1C then why print &modified gived me a different offset?

Update: I had issues with copy paste from the VM, now I am connected via Putty therefore I can copy it, but the addresses a bit changed due to the ssh thread - please note that I do check the address value  after its instantiation.
On top of it also "hacked" this code and override the modified value - as you can see my calculation / assumption look correct (esp + 0x5c), and I do override the modified variable and as you can see the address that p &modified presents is not even touched.

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffd74) at stack0/stack0.c:6
6       in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x080483f4 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483f5 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483f7 <main+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483fa <main+6>:    sub    esp,0x60
0x080483fd <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c],0x0
0x08048405 <main+17>:   lea    eax,[esp+0x1c]
0x08048409 <main+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x0804840c <main+24>:   call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x08048411 <main+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]
0x08048415 <main+33>:   test   eax,eax
0x08048417 <main+35>:   je     0x8048427 <main+51>
0x08048419 <main+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048500
0x08048420 <main+44>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048425 <main+49>:   jmp    0x8048433 <main+63>
0x08048427 <main+51>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048529
0x0804842e <main+58>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048433 <main+63>:   leave
0x08048434 <main+64>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break *(main+33)
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8048415: file stack0/stack0.c, line 13.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0804840c in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffd74)
    at stack0/stack0.c:11
11      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) x/wx $eip
0x804840c <main+24>:    0xfffefbe8
(gdb) p &modified
$6 = (volatile int *) 0xbffffd24
(gdb) p &buffer[0]
$7 = 0xbffffce4 "\377\377\377\377\364\357\377\267K\202\004\b\001"
(gdb) c
Continuing.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Breakpoint 3, 0x08048415 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffd74)
    at stack0/stack0.c:13
13      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) x/wx $esp
0xbffffc60:     0xbffffc7c
(gdb) x/64wx $esp
0xbffffc60:     0xbffffc7c      0x00000001      0xb7fff8f8      0xb7f0186e 
0xbffffc70:     0xb7fd7ff4      0xb7ec6165      0xbffffc88      0x61616161  
0xbffffc80:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161  
0xbffffc90:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffca0:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffcb0:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffcc0:     0x08040061      0x00000000      0xbffffd48      0xb7eadc76
0xbffffcd0:     0x00000001      0xbffffd74      0xbffffd7c      0xb7fe1848
0xbffffce0:     0xbffffd30      0xffffffff      0xb7ffeff4      0x0804824b
0xbffffcf0:     0x00000001      0xbffffd30      0xb7ff0626      0xb7fffab0
0xbffffd00:     0xb7fe1b28      0xb7fd7ff4      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xbffffd10:     0xbffffd48      0x6d276aaa      0x4766bcba      0x00000000
0xbffffd20:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000001      0x08048340
0xbffffd30:     0x00000000      0xb7ff6210      0xb7eadb9b      0xb7ffeff4
0xbffffd40:     0x00000001      0x08048340      0x00000000      0x08048361
0xbffffd50:     0x080483f4      0x00000001      0xbffffd74      0x08048450
(gdb) c
Continuing.
you have changed the 'modified' variable

Program exited with code 051.
```

I also added some hooks and as you can clearly see, the "p &modified" is false also "p modified".

```
Starting program: /opt/protostar/bin/stack0
eax            0xbffffc6c       -1073742740
ecx            0x35a39915       899914005
edx            0x1      1
ebx            0xb7fd7ff4       -1208123404
esp            0xbffffc50       0xbffffc50
ebp            0xbffffcb8       0xbffffcb8
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x804840c        0x804840c <main+24>
eflags         0x200286 [ PF SF IF ID ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
0xbffffc50:     0xbffffc6c      0x00000001      0xb7fff8f8      0xb7f0186e
0xbffffc60:     0xb7fd7ff4      0xb7ec6165      0xbffffc78      0xb7eada75
0xbffffc70:     0xb7fd7ff4      0x08049620      0xbffffc88      0x080482e8
0xbffffc80:     0xb7ff1040      0x08049620      0xbffffcb8      0x08048469
0xbffffc90:     0xb7fd8304      0xb7fd7ff4      0x08048450      0xbffffcb8
0xbffffca0:     0xb7ec6365      0xb7ff1040      0x0804845b      0x00000000
0x804840c <main+24>:    call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x8048411 <main+29>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804840c in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffd64) at stack0/stack0.c:11
11      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
eax            0xbffffc6c       -1073742740
ecx            0xbffffc6c       -1073742740
edx            0xb7fd9334       -1208118476
ebx            0xb7fd7ff4       -1208123404
esp            0xbffffc50       0xbffffc50
ebp            0xbffffcb8       0xbffffcb8
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x8048411        0x8048411 <main+29>
eflags         0x200246 [ PF ZF IF ID ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
0xbffffc50:     0xbffffc6c      0x00000001      0xb7fff8f8      0xb7f0186e
0xbffffc60:     0xb7fd7ff4      0xb7ec6165      0xbffffc78      0x61616161
0xbffffc70:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffc80:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffc90:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0xbffffca0:     0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161      0x61616161
0x8048411 <main+29>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]
0x8048415 <main+33>:    test   eax,eax

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1633771873, argv=0x61616161) at stack0/stack0.c:13
13      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) p &modified
$2 = (volatile int *) 0xbffffd14
(gdb) p modified
$3 = 0
(gdb)
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you compile it, what compiler version and flags? Can you upload the binary somewhere? Also note that `main` is somewhat special due to the stack alignment code, maybe that confuses gdb (although it works here).

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text; cut/paste the text itself.

Comment: @Jester I don't really know, it is taken from protostar and they have dedicated ISO which contains all the compiled files

Comment: @EmployedRussian I would, if it would let me to copy paste from the VM, but with their ISO it did not allow me, connected via Putty - now I can. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Looks like bug in gdb or in the debug info. It is using `ebp+0x5c` instead of `esp+0x5c`.

Comment: Yes I guess so too. I wanted to make sure I understand the flow correctly but I guess I felt on a buggie version thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your *complete* interaction with GDB.

Most likely answer is that you have stopped *before* the function prolog has executed, and thus GDB prints you a bogus value of `&modified`.

Example:

```
(gdb) b *main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11ad: file foo.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xffffcc44) at foo.c:6
6       {

# Note: stopped before function prolog

(gdb) p/x &modified
$1 = 0xfffffff4                    <<<--- bogus!

(gdb) s
10        modified = 0;

(gdb) p &modified
$2 = (volatile int *) 0xffffcb7c   <<<--- now correct.
```

Comment: I am actually looking at the variable after mov DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c], 0x0 - added to the q.